# Searching with multiple variables PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, variables, mysqli

I'm trying to create a search where the column and value are both variables using prepared statements. The query is where I need help.

```
$column=$_POST['filter'][0][columnName];
$value = trim($_POST['filter'][0][value]);

$stmt = $mysql->prepare("select * from TABLE WHERE $column like '%$value%'");
```

I want to be able to specify different column and value pairs to use in conjunction with eachother- so that i can search column one for one value and also column two for another value.

thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a good objective, so what's the problem?

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection attacks. Good that you're using prepared statements, bad that you're not using placeholders to actually make use of prepared statement's anti-injection features.

Comment: Robert, Im trying to figure out how to search multiple columns for multiple terms.(concisely if possible) Marc, Yes I am binding the params I just broke the code down to try and make it work -my bad its been a long day. Thanks for looking out though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PHP's `mysql` library has prepared statements. Is your $mysql variable actually a mysqli or pdo connection object?

With mysqli, your code would look like this:

```
$dbconnection = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$stmt = $dbconnection->prepare("select * from TABLE WHERE $column like '%?%'");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$value);
```

There's no way to bind a parameter for a column name, which means that you're stuck inserting `$column` directly into your query. Doing that with any value the user passed you in POST is a bit of a security hole. Since it's constrained to be the same as one of your column names, I'd suggest validating it first to make sure it's not set to something different.

Comment: yeah its mysqli, sorry. I was trying to break it down as much as possible. I'm still just trying to figure out the best way to make it work, I will be addressing security. Thanks, I did not know you couldn't bind a param for column names so that already helps me out. So what would be the best way to code that? Say I check and make sure its one of the 20 something columns I have, then what?

Comment: You can insert the column name as a variable, just like you're doing in your sample code. It doesn't provide the security that comes from binding a parameter, like you're doing with $value, but as long as you make sure it's an approved column name, then you're fine.