# Search multiple variables php/mysqli

Tags: php, variables, mysqli

Im trying to figure out the best way to search for more than one variable.

```
include('connection.inc.php');

$column= $_POST['filter'][0][columnName];
$value = $_POST['filter'][0][value];

$stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * from TABLE WHERE $column like '%?%'");
$stmt -> bind_param('s', $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

What i want to be able to do is search more than one column for more than one term.
IE: search column name for values "bob" AND column address for values "boston"
Since both the column names AND the value names are variables in an array, I wanted to know what would be the best way to do so. THANKS!

Comment: Note that your `bind_param()` won't work as expected here since you just inserted `$value` into the query.  Use instead: `$stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * from TABLE WHERE $column like '%?%'");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879471/searching-with-multiple-variables-php-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Just add an additional parameter to your where clause:

```
$column1 = $_POST['filter'][0][columnName];
$value1 = $_POST['filter'][0][value];
// Add your other variables here

$column2 = $_POST['filter'][1][columnName];
$value2 = $_POST['filter'][1][value];


$stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * from TABLE WHERE $column1=? AND $column2=?");
$stmt -> bind_param('ss', $value1,$value2);
$stmt->execute();
```

Although you might want to take a look at the way you're assigning variables for usage. A `$_POST`  with a need for so many indices per simple variable isn't normal in my experience; there has to be a better way for you to code it.

Comment: its not normal, but its a complicated thing. ive simplified it here. Using AND would work, but the number of queries varies too. So just need 1 WHERE or I could need 4.